# Como hacer para mantener el socket abierto pero limpiar la variable cliente con PHP

Tags: php

Hola tengo un programa que se conecta a un socket y este ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '5500';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Error al vincular socket con la ip en ese cliente');
socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
socket_listen($socket);
$i=0;

$file_name = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\boleta\log_'. date('d-m-Y_H_i_s') .'.txt';
$file = fopen($file_name,'w');
fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."");
fclose($file);

while(true) {
$client[++$i] = socket_accept($socket);
$message = socket_read($client[$i], 1024);
$string = str_split($message, 5); 
} 
socket_close($client[$i]);
```

El problema que existe con ello es que cada vez que el programa se ejecuta cierra el socket y tiene que volver a abrirlo como ustedes ven, y si le quito el socket_close me muestra un error porque parece que choca el socket que está abierto y el que va a abrir nuevo, yo quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder mantener el socket abierto sin la necesidad de utilizar socket_close() es decir que la creación del socket solo se haga una vez y no más de una vez.

Es posible hacer ello? crear el socket una sola vez que verifique que está abierto y si está abierto no volver a crear sino que volver a ejecutar el while() sin tener que cerrar el socket?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: mira este ejemplo: https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/

Comment: @Bryro pero si utilizan socket_close()